# EF6: ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 Code First with Oracle 12c.

I have a property that requires the data max length:

```
user.Property(u => u.PasswordHash).HasColumnType("NVARCHAR2").IsMaxLength();

PASSWORDHASH = c.String(maxLength: 32767, storeType: "nvarchar2")
```

when I try to migrate I get:

```
ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype
```

Extended DataType is enable in my database and I can create the table successfully using a script.

Comment: How long do you expect the hash of a password to be? Why would you need even 1000 characters, let alone 32000?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is below your c# code but 32767 is max length for PL/SQL if this goes with plain SQL limit is 4000. So I think you should change it to 4000.
 
The limit is in fact 4000 bytes so if you insert 2-byte character it gets less than 4000 chars.